# How to specify the correct DLL for SWT when running main?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, swt

I'm getting an error where my maven build works fine (using `mvn install`: the produced executable runs in Windows), but when I try to run main directly from IntelliJ, it is looking for SWT's GTK dlls, which is of course not correct:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    no swt-gtk-4528 in java.library.path
    no swt-gtk in java.library.path
    Can't load library: C:\Users\brandon\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-gtk-4528.dll
    Can't load library: C:\Users\brandon\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-gtk.dll

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at edu.cornell.ansci.dairy.econ.ui.MainWindow$.main(MainWindow.scala:175)
    at edu.cornell.ansci.dairy.econ.ui.MainWindow.main(MainWindow.scala)
```

In fact the actual file contents of the directory look correct, but this is not what is being looked for:

```
brandon@DESKTOP-MU8LD7O:/mnt/c/Users/brandon/.swt/lib/win32/x86_64$ ls
swt-gdip-win32-4528.dll  swt-win32-4528.dll
```

Here is an image of the run configuration in Intellij (Default JDK is Zulu - maybe I should try to install another?):

[image]

Comment: What about the `swt.jar` - there is a different version of this for each platform, you need to use the correct one.

Comment: @greg-449 I think you are on to something; I forgot that I had changed linux64 to the default maven profile, so I guess that affect the classpath; switching it back to win64 made it work. Now I need to figure out ideally how to make this run configuration independent of the maven profile (since it isn't a maven run configuration, not sure how to tell it which maven profile, or which SWT.jar, to use).